# .csproj not found when building with dockerfile

Tags: .net, docker

I've created a blank solution with rider.
This solution has 1 console app with a simple Hello World!

[image]

I've generated an automatic dockerfile by right clicking on the csproj --> Add --> Docker support.

Here is the DockerFile generated

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:7.0 AS base WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build 
WORKDIR /src 
COPY ["RootFolder/RootFolder.csproj", "RootFolder/"] 
RUN dotnet restore "RootFolder/RootFolder.csproj" 
COPY . . 
WORKDIR "/src/RootFolder" 
RUN dotnet build "RootFolder.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish 
RUN dotnet publish "RootFolder.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final 
WORKDIR /app COPY --from=publish /app/publish . 
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "RootFolder.dll"]
```

When I run a `docker build .` command

I get .csproj not found exception.

[image]

I have 0 idea why. Everything is as simple as possible. Yet my csproj is not found.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Edit: Hans Kilian Response

After using docker build ..
I get this message error:
*failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount4071044659/Dockerfile: no such file or directory*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your Dockerfile expects that the build context is the 'DockerTest' folder rather than the 'RootFolder' folder.

The context is what you specify as the last argument on the `docker build` command.

So instead of

```
docker build .
```

try

```
docker build -f Dockerfile ..
```

Another way to solve it is to move the Dockerfile up to the 'DockerTest' directory and then run `docker build .` from there.

Comment: I know have another error message: failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount4071044659/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

Comment: Ah, sorry. Then it looks for the Dockerfile in the ´DockerTest´ folder. I've updated the command so it can find the Dockerfile.